# Popen stdout reading pipe, deadlock using sleep

Tags: python, deadlock, popen

Well, I have two scripts. The a.py which prints the output of the b.py script as follows:

```
#a.py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['/Users/damian/Desktop/b.py'], shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

while p.poll() is None:
    print p.stdout.readline()


#b.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time

while 1:
    print 'some output'
    #time.sleep(1)
```

This works.But,
Why do my scripts deadlock when I uncomment the time.sleep() line?

Comment: Are you sure that b.py will not deadlock itself if executed separately? (check indentations if they are same for both lines in while 1: !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your output is probably buffered. Add a [.flush()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush) for stdout to clear it:

```
import sys
import time

while 1:
    print 'someoutput'
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Indeed, flush does it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you add `-u` to the call in `a.py` (make the output unbuffered) then you don't need to modify `b.py` script:

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen([sys.executable, '-u', '/Users/damian/Desktop/b.py'],
          stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    print line,
p.stdout.close()
if p.wait() != 0:
   raise RuntimeError("%r failed, exit status: %d" % (cmd, p.returncode))
```

See [more ways to get output from a subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12606327/4279).

Comment: Nice. Heh, also thanks for the output examples. One more proof of Python's power.