# subprocess.check_output(): show output on failure

Tags: python, subprocess

The output of `subprocess.check_output()` looks like this at the moment:

```
CalledProcessError: Command '['foo', ...]' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Is there a way to get a better error message?

I want to see `stdout` and `stderr`.

Comment: I use subx since several months. See: https://github.com/guettli/subx#subprocesscheck_output-vs-subxcall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't want to write more code, just to get a good error message, I wrote [subx](https://github.com/guettli/subx)

From the docs:

> subprocess.check_output() vs subx.call()
>
> Look, compare, think and decide what message helps your more.
>
> subprocess.check_output()::
>
> ```
> CalledProcessError: Command '['cat', 'some-file']' returned non-zero exit status 1
> ```
>
> sub.call()::
>
> ```
> SubprocessError: Command '['cat', 'some-file']' returned non-zero exit status 1:
> stdout='' stderr='cat: some-file: No such file or directory'
> ```
>
> ... especially if the code fails in a production environment where
>   reproducing the error is not easy, subx can call help you to spot the
>   source of the failure.

Answer (score 14):

Redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT`.

**Example** *from the interpreter*:

```
>>> try:
...   subprocess.check_output(['ls','-j'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
... except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
...   print('error>', e.output, '<')
...
```

Will *throw*:

```
error> b"ls: invalid option -- 'j'\nTry `ls --help' for more information.\n" <
```

**Explantion**

From [**check_output**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) documentation:

> To **also capture standard error** in the result, use
>   `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`

Comment: Are you capturing STDOUT here or STDERR?

Comment: For me this worked - I just needed to print the exception output to get what I wanted (the failure text of the command while still catching the exceptoin).

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `check_output()`, use [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) and [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) instead:

```
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(['cmd', '--optional-switch'])
>>> output, errors = proc.communicate()
```

Here `output` is data from `stdout` and `errors` is data from `stderr`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion that a perfect scenario to use `sys.excepthook`! You just have to filter what you would like to be formatted as you want in the `if` statement. With this solution, it will cover every exception of your code without having to refract everything!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import subprocess

# Create the exception handler function
def my_excepthook(type, value, traceback):
    # Check if the exception type name is CalledProcessError
    if type.__name__ == "CalledProcessError":
        # Format the error properly
        sys.stderr.write("Error: " + type.__name__ + "\nCommand: " + value.cmd + "\nOutput: " + value.output.strip())
    # Else we format the exception normally
    else:
        sys.stderr.write(str(value))

# We attach every exceptions to the function my_excepthook
sys.excepthook = my_excepthook

# We duplicate the exception
subprocess.check_output("dir /f",shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

You can modify the output as you wish, here is the actual ouput:

```
Error: CalledProcessError
Command: dir /f
Output: Invalid switch - "f".
```

Comment: This changes the global stuff which can effect code which gets executed hours after calling the lines of the above question. Yes, your solution works, but I prefer a solution which does no global change. I have a problem with the library. I would like to solve the issue at this level. (for example use an alternative library).