# Running a C executable inside a python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, executable

I have written a `C code` where I have converted one file format to another file format. To run my `C code`, I have taken one command line argument : `filestem`.

I executed that code using : `./executable_file filestem > outputfile`

Where I have got my desired output inside `outputfile`

Now I want to take that executable and run within a python code.

I am trying like :

```
import subprocess
import sys
filestem = sys.argv[1];
subprocess.run(['/home/dev/executable_file', filestem , 'outputfile'])
```

But it is unable to create the `outputfile`. I think some thing should be added to solve the `>` issue. But unable to figure out. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get all of the output from my .exe using subprocess and Popen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600892/how-do-i-get-all-of-the-output-from-my-exe-using-subprocess-and-popen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) has optional `stdout` argument, you might give it file handle, so in your case something like

```
import subprocess
import sys
filestem = sys.argv[1]
with open('outputfile','wb') as f:
    subprocess.run(['/home/dev/executable_file', filestem],stdout=f)
```

should work. I do not have ability to test it so please run it and write if it does work as intended

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

> **NOTE** - Tested in CentOS 7, using Python 2.7

**1.** Try `pexpect`:

```
"""Usage: executable_file argument ("ex. stack.py -lh")"""
import pexpect

filestem = sys.argv[1]
# Using ls -lh >> outputfile as an example
cmd = "ls {0} >> outputfile".format(filestem)
command_output, exitstatus = pexpect.run("/usr/bin/bash -c '{0}'".format(cmd), withexitstatus=True)
if exitstatus == 0:
    print(command_output)
else:
    print("Houston, we've had a problem.")
```

**2.** Run `subprocess` with `shell=true` **(Not recommended)**:

```
"""Usage: executable_file argument ("ex. stack.py -lh")"""
import sys
import subprocess

filestem = sys.argv[1]
# Using ls -lh >> outputfile as an example
cmd = "ls {0} >> outputfile".format(filestem)
result = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(cmd), shell=True)  # or subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
print(result)
```

It works, but python.org frowns upon this, due to the chance of a shell injection: see ["Security Considerations" in the subprocess documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations)

**3.** If you must use `subprocess`, run each command separately and take the SDTOUT of the previous command and pipe it into the STDIN of the next command:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
stdout_data, stderr_data = p.communicate()
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=stdout_data, stdout=PIPE)
etc...
```

Good luck with your code!

Comment: Why is pexpect recommended when there are straightforward ways of doing this with the standard library? By the way, subprocess has evolved considerably in Python 3.x.

Comment: You are right in both cases; I just recommended Pexpect out of all the code I tested. I edited my answer to reflect that.