# Extracting output from .exe in real-time and storing it

Tags: python, extract, executable

I have a `.exe` programme that produces real-time data. I want to extract the output when running the programme in real-time, however It's my first time trying this out, and so I wanted help in approaching this.

I have opened it with the following:

```
cmd = r'/Applications/StockSpy Realtime Stocks Quote.app/Contents/MacOS/StockSpy Realtime Stocks Quote'

import subprocess

with open('output.txt', 'wb') as f:
    subprocess.check_call(cmd, stdout=f)

# to read line by line
with open('output.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
# output = qx(cmd)
```

with the aim to store the output. However, it does not save any of the output, I get a blank textfile.

I managed to save the output by following this code:

```
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_call as x

with open(os.devnull, 'rb') as DEVNULL, open('output.txt', 'wb') as f:
    x(cmd, stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=f, stderr=STDOUT)
```

from [How do I get all of the output from my .exe using subprocess and Popen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600892/how-do-i-get-all-of-the-output-from-my-exe-using-subprocess-and-popen)

Comment: Can you specify what information do you want to scrape?

Comment: @F.Hoque For this specific case, I wanted to scrape the stock prices from the app linked in the post. Otherwise, I wanted to know whether scrapy has the capability to scrape apple store downloaded apps, or if python libraries exist for this. I know that websites have an html structure, and so the app may not permit scraping through this, but surely it holds data in the back-end, perhaps this is accessible?

Comment: Are you asking if you can get scrapy to work on an iphone?

Comment: if those apps you mentioned have the same information on the web, then scrapy can get it...

Comment: @alexpdev they do not share the info on the web only in the app. The app is built with `c`, and they have an executable that grabs the real-time data from their database with websocket. I have changed my question, so it addresses a specific focus on how to get real-time data from the executable.

Comment: What you're doing does not RUN the app.  It just opens the executable as a data file.  What you need, I believe, is `subprocess.Popen`, so you can run the application and read the output that it prints.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for the suggestion, I briefly looked into this before but wasn't sure this was what I needed. I will dig into it some more. On a additional note; could this run the programme, extract and store the data in real-time, say if I got the data and connected it to an sql database, without stopping (unless I quit it)

Comment: Sure, that's just coding.   HOWEVER, whatever they're doing with a Websocket, you could do inside your own app.  You don't really need the application.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be achieved with python using something like this:

```
import subprocess
with subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/executable'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
    data = proc.stdout.read()   # the data variable will contain the 
                                # what would usually be the output 
    """Do something with data..."""
```